# URL encoding in Jersey/Java webservice

Tags: java, url, jersey, urldecode

My Java/Jersey webservice

```
../rest/services/save/{url}
```

I am trying to post data with a url like this example:

```
"http://.../save/mike|california|usa"
```

crashes my webservice and crashes with this error "message Illegal character in path at index 100". The url is coming in `"http://.../save/mike%7Ccalifornia%7Cusa"`.

What do I need to do to have my webservice accept such url with "|" for instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the `|`'s in the url as `%7C`.  `|` is an illegal character, so this is necessary.